# Unknown reason why this error is coming up

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, project, drawrectangle

I am just a beginner in python. My code worked a day ago, but when I reopened it, it stopped working suddenly. I am creating a painting program and made a rectangle shape, but the error comes up always on one line of code and it has never done that.

I did not touch my code and now the program runs but the error occurs when I try to draw the rectangle itself. I attempted to redefine the "screenCap" variable but it did not help

> ```py
> ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Mazen\Desktop\paint project 1\paintproject.py", line 498, in
> <module>     screen.blit(screenCap,(400,70)) TypeError: argument 1
> must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method >>>
> ```

```
from pygame import *
from random import *
from math import *
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.withdraw() #hides the extra window

width,height=1280,695
screen=display.set_mode((width,height))
RED=(255,0,0)
GREY=(127,127,127)
BLACK=(0,0,0)
BLUE=(0,0,255)
GREEN=(0,255,0)
YELLOW=(255,255,0)
WHITE=(255,255,255)

tool="NO TOOL"
omx,omy,mx,my=0,0,0,0
sx=0 #Starting x
sy=0 
col=(0,0,0)
Shaperad=1 #thickness for all unfilled shapes
Prad=1 #thickness for the pencil
rad=3 #thickness for the brush, eraser, highlighter and spray paint
hlighter=Surface((20,20),SRCALPHA)#for changing the transparency
r,g,b,a=(255,165,0,255) #(r-red,g-green,b-blue,a-alpha)these variables are used to chnage the colours of the highlighter including transparency (ALPHA) 


#background
backgroundPic=image.load("images/background.jpg")
screen.blit(backgroundPic,(0,0))

#the canvas
canvas=Rect(400,70,850,500)
draw.rect(screen,WHITE,canvas)

#tools
pencil=Rect(30,180,60,60)
eraser=Rect(110,180,60,60)
brush=Rect(190,180,60,60)
spraypaint=Rect(30,260,60,60)
highlighter=Rect(110,260,60,60)
oval=Rect(30,340,60,60)
rectangle=Rect(110,340,60,60)
line=Rect(190,340,60,60)
filledoval=Rect(30,420,60,60)
filledrect=Rect(110,420,60,60)
polygon=Rect(190,420,60,60)

#displaying tools
draw.rect(screen,BLUE,rectangle)
draw.rect(screen,BLUE,line)
draw.rect(screen,BLUE,oval)
draw.rect(screen,BLUE,filledoval)
draw.rect(screen,BLUE,filledrect)
draw.rect(screen,BLUE,polygon)

#tool photos
rectanglePic=image.load("images/rectangle.png")
screen.blit(rectanglePic,(115,346))
linePic=image.load("images/line.png")
screen.blit(linePic,(190,345))
ovalPic=image.load("images/oval.png")
screen.blit(ovalPic,(33,340))


screenCap=screen.subsurface(canvas).copy()#taking a PARTIAL screen shot
canvas2=screen.subsurface(canvas).copy()#clear copy of the canvas
Rlist=[canvas2]
Ulist=[canvas2]

running=True
while running:
    for evt in event.get():
       if evt.type==QUIT:
           running=False
    screenCap=screen.subsurface(canvas).copy()
        #controling thickness
       if evt.type==KEYDOWN: #some key was pressed
           if evt.key==K_UP and tool=="pencil":
               Prad+=1 #the thickness of the pencil increases by 1
               if Prad>3: #Checks to see if  the thicknes goes over 3 and if it does, then it becomes 3
                   Prad=3
           if evt.key==K_UP:
               Shaperad+=1
               if Shaperad>30:
                   Shaperad=30
           if evt.key==K_UP:
              rad+=1
              if rad>40:
                  rad=40
           if evt.key==K_DOWN:
               Prad-=1
               if Prad==0:
                   Prad=1
               Shaperad-=1
               if Shaperad==0:
                   Shaperad=1
               rad-=1
               if rad==0:
                   rad=1

        #mouse visibility
       if evt.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           mouse.set_visible(False)
       if evt.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP:
           mouse.set_visible(True)

       if evt.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           sx,sy=evt.pos
           screenCap=screen.subsurface(canvas).copy()#taking a screenshot
       if evt.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP:
           screen.set_clip(canvas)

        #undo
       if evt.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           if mb[0]==1:
               click=True
           screenCap=screen.copy #taking a screenshot
           sx,sy=mouse.get_pos()

       if evt.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP:
           if canvas.collidepoint(mx,my): #If the canvas rect/s collidepoint is the mouse (mouse touches canvas)
               duplicate=screen.subsurface(canvas).copy() #makes a duplicate of the surface of the canvas
               Ulist.append(duplicate) #appends the dupolicated surface of the canvas

    mx,my=mouse.get_pos()
    mb=mouse.get_pressed()



    #hover colour change
    if pencil.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,pencil,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,pencil,3)
    if eraser.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,eraser,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,eraser,3)
    if rectangle.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,rectangle,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,rectangle,3)
    if line.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,line,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,line,3)
    if oval.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,oval,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,oval,3)
    if brush.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,brush,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,brush,3)
    if spraypaint.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,spraypaint,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,spraypaint,3)
    if highlighter.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,highlighter,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,highlighter,3)
    if filledoval.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,filledoval,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,filledoval,3)
    if filledrect.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,filledrect,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,filledrect,3)
    if polygon.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,polygon,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,polygon,3)
    if gingerbread.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,gingerbread,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,gingerbread,3)
    if gift.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,gift,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,gift,3)
    if santa.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,santa,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,santa,3)
    if sleigh.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,sleigh,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,sleigh,3)
    if stalking.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,stalking,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,stalking,3)
    if elf.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,elf,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,elf,3)
    if tree.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,tree,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,tree,3)
    if mistletoe.collidepoint(mx,my):
        draw.rect(screen,BLUE,mistletoe,3)
    else:
        draw.rect(screen,GREEN,mistletoe,3)


    #tool selection        
    if mb[0]==1 and rectangle.collidepoint(mx,my):
        tool="rectangle"
        draw.rect(screen,RED,rectangle,3)

    if mb[0]==1 and line.collidepoint(mx,my):
        tool="line"
        draw.rect(screen,RED,line,3)

    if mb[0]==1 and oval.collidepoint(mx,my):
        tool="oval"
        draw.rect(screen,RED,oval,3)

    if mb[0]==1 and save.collidepoint(mx,my):
        try:
            fname=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".png")
            print(fname)
            if fname!="": #This checks if a file name has been entered
                image.save(screen.subsurface(canvasRect),fname) #Saving the picture
            image.save(screen.copy(),fname)
        except:
            print("Saving error")
    if mb[0]==1 and load.collidepoint(mx,my):
        try:
            fname=filedialog.askopenfilename()
            if fname!="":
                Pic=image.load(fname)
                width=Pic.get_width() #recieves the width of the image/file that is being opened
                height=Pic.get_height() #recieves the height of the image/file that is being opened
                if width>400: #checks to see if the width of the picture is larger than the width of the whole canvas
                    file=transform.scale(Pic,(400,height)) #changes the width if it is too large
                if height>70: #checks to see if the height of the picture is larger than the height of the whole canvas
                    file=transform.scale(Pic,(width,70)) #changes the height if it is too large
                if height>70 and width>400:
                    file=transform.scale(Pic,(400,70)) #This transforms the width if its larger
                draw.rect(screen,WHITE,canvas) #This draws a white rectangle so that when you blit a picture it covers everything, including your previous drawings
                screen.blit(file,(canvas)) #This blits the picture onto the canvas
        except:
            print("load error")

    if mb[0]==1 and redo.collidepoint(mx,my):
        if len(Rlist)!=1: #checks to see if the redo list is not equal to one
            Ulist.append(Rlist[-1])#brings back the last thing that was in the Ulist
            Rlist.pop()#removes the last thing on the Rlist
            screen.blit(Ulist[-1],(canvas))

    if mb[0]==1 and undo.collidepoint(mx,my):
        if len(Ulist)!=1:#checks to make sure that the length of the Ulist is not 1 because if it was not 1 it will undo, but if it is 1 and you click undo, the canvas will erase 
            Rlist.append(Ulist[-1]) 
            Ulist.pop() 
            screen.blit(Ulist[-1],(canvas))

    #using tools
    if mb[0]==1:
        if canvas.collidepoint(mx,my):
            screen.set_clip(canvas)
            if tool=="eraser":
                 #no spaces for eraser
                dx=mx-omx #run
                dy=my-omy #rise
                dist=int(sqrt(dx**2+dy**2))
                for i in range(1,dist):
                    cx=int(omx+i*dx/dist)
                    cy=int(omy+i*dy/dist)
                    draw.circle(screen,WHITE,(cx,cy),rad)
            if tool=="rectangle":
                screen.blit(screenCap,(400,70))
                draw.rect(screen,col,(sx,sy,mx-sx,my-sy),Shaperad)
                #these rects are to fix the gap error when increasing the thickness of the rectangle
                draw.rect(screen,col,(sx-(Shaperad/2-1),sy-(Shaperad/2-1),Shaperad,Shaperad))
                draw.rect(screen,col,(sx-(Shaperad/2-1),my-(Shaperad/2),Shaperad,Shaperad))
                draw.rect(screen,col,(mx-(Shaperad/2),sy-(Shaperad/2-1),Shaperad,Shaperad))
                draw.rect(screen,col,(mx-(Shaperad/2),my-(Shaperad/2),Shaperad,Shaperad))
```

Comment: Instead of manually indicating which line triggered the error, I suggest including the full traceback in your question as it contains the line that caused it and other information that may be useful in identifying the issue.

Comment: @TomasFarias sorry, is this better?

Comment: Could you please provide the whole error message in a separate code block, for example:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "typeerror.py", line 1, in <module>
    print("%d" % ([1,2]))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list
`

Comment: @SergeyNudnov i included the entire error in the text

Comment: Can you include some more code?

Comment: OK, from the code shown it looks all correct. However code indents are not consistent and that may cause your problem. In Python the correct indents are paramount! Cleanup your file and ensure all blocks have consistent 4 space indents. Then update question with well aligned code. Also did you provide all code lines under the `while running:` loop? If not, scroll over them and check for any lines with `screenCap` variable. You must redefined it somewhere below, in code you didn't provide there.

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes it is supposed to be there because if it is not is chnages the amount of arguments in the code

Comment: `screenCap=screen.copy #taking a screenshot` -- Oops, I think it should be `screenCap=screen.copy() #taking a screenshot`

Comment: @FredLarson, I hope you won't mind that I posted the same as an asnwer

Comment: @SergeyNudnov: Not at all, though I'm wondering if the question should be closed as just a typo rather than answered.

Comment: @FredLarson, it was obvious from very beginning that the brackets were missed somewhere. It could be useful for beginners on what should be done to find an issue

Answer (score 1):

You have missed brackets `()` there `screenCap=screen.copy #taking a screenshot`. Should be:

```
        #undo
       if evt.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           if mb[0]==1:
               click=True
           screenCap=screen.copy() #taking a screenshot
           sx,sy=mouse.get_pos()
```

Couple of advices to you as to beginner in Python:

- This approach - `import *`:

  ```
  from pygame import *
  from random import *
  from math import *
  from tkinter import *
  ```

  could give a lot of troubles by shadowing names from imported modules. For example, any names in `pygame`, which are the same as names in `tkinter`, could be shadowed.

  The much cleaner approach is to import just names which you use, for example:

  ```
  from pygame import display, ...
  from tkinter import Tk, ...
  ```
- As I mentioned in my comments already, keep your lines indented consistently
- Download, install and use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) Community Edition - it will highlight code with errors and design issues - that will be great help in learning Python and faster development